# this type of methods should be treated as singular or plural

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

For example, is this correct?

> This type of methods has achieved great success.

or it should be

> This type of methods have achieved great success.

Comment: This is certainly an interesting question in its own right, but you should be aware that you are not very likely to encounter "this type of methods" in the first place. You are way more likely to see "these types of methods" or "this type of method".

Answer (score 1):

If you really are talking about method *types*, then:

- One method *type* --> use "This type of method has...".
- More than one method *type* --> use "These types of method have..."

In using "this" vs. "these" and "has" vs. "have", it doesn't matter how many methods there are, just how many *types*. In the above, it is admittedly awkward to say "types of method", but I believe it is correct if refers to several types of the same method. You could argue that every type is a different method, so it would also be correct to use the plural "methods" in that case of "types". In any case, the plurality of "type" has to agree with "this/these" and "has/have".

If "type" is dispensable, you might consider:

- "These methods have..."
- "This method has..."

...depending on what you define as a "method" (e.g. a group of methods used together could be defined as a method itself) and how many methods you're referring to.

Comment: Thank you very much. In this context, I want to emphasize that this type of method also have some variations compared with other types of methods. So is it correct that 'This type of methods...'

Comment: Would you say that all variations belongs to one group that you could call a type?

Comment: Yes. These variations belong one type.

Comment: One type = singular, so it's "This type of method has...".

Comment: +1. And just to emphasise to @Lixin, "this type of methods" is *technically* ok but a native speaker would never use that construction.